# How to unzip folder in google cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

My dataset is in the following form with 3 folders labelled 0, 5, 10 and each has about 200,000 images :

```
frames_zip :
           ->0
           ->5
           ->10
```

I have been trying to unzip my folder with the Dataflow API using Bulk Decompress Cloud Storage Files but the folders get unzipped into a single file. I have tried everything in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541026/how-do-i-unzip-a-zip-file-in-google-cloud-storage) as well but nothing is working.

Comment: What is the total size of an unzipped file? I might have a workaround

Comment: 23GB I'm thinking I might just zip each folder up individually then run it through the Bulk Decompress API

Comment: Do you need to perform this unzip only 1 time? or at least asynchronously?

Comment: Just one time and I tried the Bulk Decompress on each folder individually and they are converted to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several way to achieve this.

- If it's one time, simply

  - create a compute engine,
  - install zip on it
  - Download your file from Storage
  - unzip the file locally
  - upload the uncompressed file and folder architecture to Cloud Storage `gsutil -m cp -r ./local-dir gs://myBucket`
  - Delete the VM
- If it's a periodic task to uncompress the file (for example every week)

  - Create a Cloud Build pipeline, with 1 step which perform exactly the same things as before with the VM (install zip, download the zip files, uncompress and send back the uncompressed file).
  - Schedule periodically Cloud Build pipeline with [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart)
  - Cloud Build is serverless and you can have up to [1000Gb of local storage](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#options)

> diskSizeGb: Use the diskSizeGb option to request a custom disk size for your build. The maximum size you can request is 1000 GB.

Comment: Worked perfectly I already had the unzipped folder locally I just had to set up gcloud on my laptop and upload it.