# Handle full snapshot data coming as part files in data pipeline in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, pipeline, google-cloud-storage

I am working on writing data pipelines for our data lake using GCP.
We have a requirement of getting a full snapshot for one of our data sources.
Since the snapshot is big in size, the ingestion spark system creates multiple part files and copies them into our landing bucket.
The file path looks as follows

<landing_bucket_name>/<datasource_name>/yyyy-mm-dd/<file_name>.parquet

Example path: vendor_data/datasource1/2023-08-01/file1.parquet

Whenever any file gets copied into our landing bucket, google cloud storage triggers the cloud function and provides the path of the newly copied file. The cloud function invokes the pipeline which process this file and copies the data into BigQuery.

As our system is event-based, we can not process all the files at the same time. Also, this data is a full snapshot in nature, so the whole data copy into Bigquery should be atomic in nature.

The current implementation simply appends every file data into the target table. We have also added one extra column named file_date in the final table whose value is populated from the date in the file path. We have created a view on top of the final target table, where we filter the data with the latest file_date. This approach works fine, once all the files which belong to one snapshot are loaded into the target table as the view can filter the latest snapshot using the file_date column.

The problem happens during the time when part files are getting loaded. During this interval, the view will give an incomplete snapshot.

One solution for this problem is to get some notification that informs us that all the part files belonging to the snapshot have been copied into the landing bucket, and then we have one extra task which merges all the part files into one single file. But since the ingestion is done by external systems, we can not enforce such constraints on them.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your requirements by providing more details on how you are taking the snapshot and the type of view (views or materialized view) you are using?

Comment: @kiranmathew
The snapshot will be provided by some external source. Think like at a certain time of day, they will dump n files in a location. All the n files combined will be seen as full snapshot.
We are using simple views to filter by file_date column to see the latest snapshot

Comment: Hi @Harbeer Kadian,According to my understanding, your issue may be caused by an incomplete loading of the source file. In this case, you can choose to either use some notification methods to be notified when files are fully loaded or decide a time interval to upload the files fully and query the view after the period. Can you take a look at [example1](https://medium.com/@joshlaird/ensuring-youtube-data-integrity-using-data-transfer-files-with-gcps-pub-sub-composer-20aee17928a4) and [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71922477/)?