# How to run a one-off Python unzipping script (19Gb .7z archive) on GC?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, 7zip

I need to extract files from the archive on a one-off basis. The Python code that can handle the task is very simple:

```
from py7zr import unpack_7zarchive
import shutil

shutil.register_unpack_format('7zip', ['.7z'], unpack_7zarchive)
path = 'gs://my_bucket/my_archive.7z'
shutil.unpack_archive(path, '')
```

I need it to run on the cloud because the archive is huge (19Gb).

There are many unzipping solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541026/how-do-i-unzip-a-zip-file-in-google-cloud-storage), but all Pythonic solutions are run as Google Functions, and Google Functions have a [16Gb memory limit](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas).

Comment: The file is too big for Cloud Shell (max total space 5 GB). The only Google service that I recommend for your use case is Compute Engine.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why do you need such a large archive extracted on GC? (Do you really need that?) What do you want to do with the extracted  memberfiles? Do you need all files, or only a fraction of them, with a small total size?

Comment: @pts it's an archived XML file, I need all the data it contains to be transferred into a BigQuery data table.

Comment: You can either use the correct service (Compute Engine) or write some fairly complicated code to read segments of the 7zip archive into memory and update BigQuery. However, even will that complicated code, performance would suck because of how BiqQuery is designed for updates and the multiple network transfers that would be required from Cloud Storage.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks, I am using Compute Engine. Which cloud, in your opinion, would be the most straightforward/efficient to use for this task: AWS, Azure or GCloud? (asking because you have expert knowledge in all clouds)

Comment: Since your data is stored in Cloud Storage and your destination is BigQuery, I recommend Google Cloud. However, for 19 GB of total data, it really won't matter provided you select regions that are close to each other.

Comment: Maybe `py7zr` can extract the member files in a streaming way to a Python iterator, without creating a file on local disk. And you can feed that data from Python code to BigQuery. Even then you may have to split it and retry multiple times, because inserting that much data at once may fail with a timeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting as a community wiki as per @JohnHanley's comment:

> The file is too big for Cloud Shell (max total space 5 GB). The only Google service that I recommend for your use case is Compute Engine.